# How to count, in R, the number of records (i.e., rows, cells) in a column belonging to a combination of treatments in the same dataframe?

Tags: r

This is my first question in this forum and I have limited experience with R, so my apologies if the question is unclear in some way or if it is too basic.

I have a dataframe called values that consists of a sample number column, two factor variables (H and W), and several number columns (named as number intervals after a cut), as follows:

```
sample  H   W   (12.95,13]  (13,13.05]  (13.05,13.1]    (13.1,13.15]
130 bg  d   0   0   0   0
131 bg  d   0   0   0   0
132 bg  d   0   0   0   0
133 x   i   0   0   0   0
134 x   i   0   0   0   0
135 x   i   0   0   0   0
136 x   i   0   0   0   0
137 x   i   0   0   0   0
138 x   i   0   0   0   0
139 x   i   0   0   0   0
140 x   i   0   0   0   0
141 x   i   0   35947.65    0   0
142 x   i   0   0   0   0
143 x   i   0   0   0   0
144 x   i   0   0   0   0
145 x   i   0   0   0   73709.67
146 x   i   0   0   0   0
147 x   i   21756.63    0   32362.41    0
148 x   i   0   0   0   0
149 x   i   0   0   0   0
150 x   i   0   0   0   0
151 x   i   0   0   0   0
152 x   c   0   0   0   0
153 x   c   0   0   0   0
154 x   c   0   0   0   0
155 x   c   0   0   0   32578.03
```

I need to count how many rows in each of the number columns for each treatment combination and sample number have values greater than 0. I have tried the aggregate, count and sum functions but have had no success so far.

Could someone help me out with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us your desired output too?

Comment: just to clarify, you want to "group by" the variables H and W, right?  And you want to count only the nonzero values of the next four columns, by group?  (What are the real column names, btw?)

Comment: I can try to explain it better. The output should be the sum of the number of rows in each numeric column (which are readings from an experiment) greater than 0 for each combination of H and W. Thus, I do want to group by H and W and count the nonzero values of these next four columns. The column names are just the numbers, which come directly from a mass spectrometer software.

Answer (score 2):

With data table (and assuming `df` is your data frame):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[`colname`>0, .N, by=list(H, W, sample)]
```

or

```
setDT(df)[`colname`>0, .N, by=list(H, W)]
```

if you don't care about `sample`.

Where you should replace `colname` with the name of the particular column you're looking at. This would be easier for me to check if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
#replicable example
set.seed(123)
values <- data.frame(sample=1:100,
                     a=rep(1,100),
                     b=rep(c(1,2),50),
                     v1=rbinom(100,1,.1) * runif(100),
                     v2=rbinom(100,1,.1) * runif(100),
                     v3=rbinom(100,1,.1) * runif(100)
                     )

aggregate(cbind(v1, v2, v3) ~ a + b, # apply fcn to LHS grouped by RHS
          data=values,              
          FUN=function(x) sum(x>0)  # sum of TRUE v>0's is count of v's greater than 0 
          )
#   a b v1 v2 v3
# 1 1 1  4  4  7
# 2 1 2  3  6  2
```

Comment: How does that check for certain columns having values >  0 ?

Comment: After re-reading the question, I believe you're right, though it's still not clear to me what the OP wants.  I'll re-answer it.  I agree that data.table is very useful here, but it can be frustrating to novices, and learning how to do it in base is a good exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't get it (my solution seems to be very simple), but I just apply on rows the sum of where columns are all different from 0.
The output is a numeric vector with length equal to the number of row of you data where:

- 0 means there is no one column with a value other than 0
- 1 means there is at least one column with a value greater than 0 and so on...

  ```
   apply(!df[, 4:7] == 0, 1, sum)

  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
  ```

Answer (score 0):

An imperfect solution using `plyr` (I am pretty sure `dplyr` package can do even better job, but I am less familiar with it)

The downside is that sums have to be calculated for each column separately - if there are 3 or 4 of them, it is OK, but for 100 intervals that wouldn't be viable.

```
##Generate fake data with 3 samples, 2 factors 3 levels each 
##and 3 observations per combination
df <- expand.grid(sample = letters[1:3], 
                  f1 = paste0('x', 1:3), 
                  f2 = paste0('y', 1:3))
df <- rbind(df, df, df)
nums <- matrix(rnorm(4*nrow(df)), ncol = 4)
colnames(nums) <- paste0('val_', 1:4)
nums[nums < 1] <- 0
df <- cbind(df, nums)

##Summarize
require(plyr)
ddply(df, .(sample, f1, f2), summarize, 
           sum_1 = sum(val_1 > 0),
           sum_2 = sum(val_2 > 0))
```